# How to reinterpret bytes between types in js?

Tags: javascript

In c++, reinterpreting the meaning of a bunch of bytes is easy, here's from integer to std::string and back to show what I mean

```
std::string pack_in_string(int v) {
    std::string ret;
    ret.reserve(4);
    *reinterpret_cast<int*>(const_cast<char*>(ret.c_str())) = v;
    return ret;
}

int extract_from_string(std::string str) {
    return *reinterpret_cast<const int*>(str.c_str());
}

int main()
{
    auto str = pack_in_string(10);
    auto val = extract_from_string(str);
    std::cout << val;
}
```

Even though js isn't strictly typed on the surface, AFAIK it internally still differentiates between strings, numbers and objects. I'm interested in packing numbers as 32b ints into strings and vice versa. Can it be done?

Comment: Take a look at [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays)

Comment: While it's allowed to use arrays of characters for storage of unrelated types, I'm not sure that plain casting is allowed and won't break strict aliasing. I think you have to use explicit byte-wise copying (e.g. `std::copy` or maybe even `std::memcpy`).